# git, squashing commits on the fly

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I have a local git repo, one remote repo.
I made 5 commits to local repo since last pull from remote.

Now I need to push to remote. And I need to squash my last 5 commits.

I can do it by `git rebase -i HEAD~5`

But it's not good. I don't want to change anything in my local repo. I want to push one squashed commit to remote and leave 5 unchanged commits in my local repo.

Any ideas?

UPD:
what about if I have my local repo with 5 commits. and I need to create new remote repo to share my code with others. How to squash commits for this new repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight variation from [Titas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750495/titas)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13669011/6309), without touching your `master` branch, and squashing on a new branch (that you would push to your new repo)

```
 git remote add newrepo url://of/your/new/repo
 git checkout -b newbranch master
 git merge --squash master 
 git push -u newrepo newbranch:master
```

But that would push the full history of master, +1 (squashed) commit, on your new repo.

If you wanted a branch new history, with your repo as after the 5 new commits, it is easier to:

- clone locally your repo,
- remove the `.git` in that local clone,
- `git init.` (ie, re-create a new local git repo from all the existing files),
- add everything and do one commit,
- add your remote (to your *new* remote repo),
- and push that one commit of your new local repo.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to keep your five commits for reference, maybe you should work in a branch with them.

1. `git branch new-branch master`
2. Do your commits. Since you have done this, just reset head of master:

   `git reset --hard HEAD~5`
3. `git merge --squash master new-branch`
4. `git push`

You will end up with squashed commit on `master` and `origin/master` and 5 commits on `new-branch`.

Comment: +1. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427238/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-merge-squash-and-rebase/2427520#2427520

Comment: yes. It's a good choise. But I posted question that describes my situation not exactly :). I have 5 commits and need to push them to the NEW (empty) remote repo/ So I don't have tag, which exist in my local and i my remote repo ... Therefore I asked about "on the fly" squashing...