# How to rebase after squashing commits in the original branch?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I have

```
A--B--C master
       \
        D branch0
```

Then I squash `B` and `C` into `B'`.
How do I rebase `branch0` such that it looks like this:

```
A--B' master
    \
     D branch0
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use the `--onto` argument to git rebase, which changes the baseline that git replays work on.

```
git checkout branch0
```

At this state you should still see **C** in your git history.

```
git rebase --onto B' C
```

This translates to: *Take all commits in my current branch since commit **C** (In your case that's just **D**) and play back on top of **B'***

You can also use the optional `<branch>` argument to do both the checkout and rebase at once:

```
git rebase --onto B' C branch0
```

Comment: Without checkout (shorter): `git rebase --onto master C branch0`

Comment: Thanks. I have added that suggestion to the answer. I have also reordered the onto and upstream arguments to rebase to match yours (even though reversed works doing a brief test) which matches the git man page.

Comment: You can skip merge conflicts by telling git to use whatever the `C` branch has to offer with `strategy-option`: `git rebase --strategy-option ours --onto B' C`

Comment: It's worth clarifying that "since commit C" is exclusive, i.e., this should be one commit before the first commit that you wish to be replayed.

Answer (score 51):

I've run into a similar problem when using squash-merge on PRs when you have branches off of branches.

My common example is if I have one feature branch (`feature-a`). I push some commits to that branch. Then I create another feature branch off of that (`feaure-b-off-a`). Then I squash-merge `feature-a` into main, I'll see duplicate commits in the PR of `feature-b-off-a` into main.

To fix this, we can use a `rebase --onto` like the accepted answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902693/1759443). But the manual work of that is finding `C` (I refer to common-ancestor below). Rewritten another way:

`git rebase --onto main common-ancestor feature-b-off-a`

- *Take all the commits between `common-ancestor` and `feature-b-off-a` and rebase them onto `main`*

Fortunately, `git` has a way of finding the [common ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549155/1759443) between two branches:

`git merge-base feature-b-off-a feature-a`

---

### TL;DR:

```sh
# This will print out the 'common-ancestor' commit between the commits/branches causing the problem
git merge-base feature-b-off-a feature-a
# Take all the commits between common-ancestor and feature-b-off-a and rebase them onto main
git rebase --onto main <common-ancestor> feature-b-off-a
# Then you'll need to force push since it's a rebase
git push -f origin feature-b-off-a
```

#### Your PR into main should now only show the new commits.

---

#### Bonus git-alias

Note: This assumes your flow is squash-merging both into `main`

```sh
git config --global alias.rebase-onto '!f() { git rebase --onto main $(git merge-base "$1" "$2") "$1"; }; f'
```

Which you'd call with:

```sh
git rebase-onto feature-b-off-a feature-a
# Then you'll need to force push since it's a rebase
git push -f origin feature-b-off-a
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick way I can think of is,

`git checkout branch0`

Note down the sha of the D commit by `git log`

`git checkout master`

Now rename the branch0 to branch1

`git branch -m branch0 branch1`

`A--B' master
    \
     D branch1`

Now delete branch1

`git branch -D branch1`

Create a branch0 again as follows.
`git checkout -b branch0`

`A--B' - master&branch0`
After the above command master and branch0 are same. Only change we need to make in branch0 is get the commit D.

`git cherry-pick D`

Now branch0 looks as follows

`A--B' master
    \
     D branch0`