# github PR is mixed up with past commits that have already been merged

Tags: github

I forked an open-source repo so that I could add some commits and make a pull request. After that **pull request was merged** GitHub was still stating, that my branch was 'x commits ahead' of main, even though it wasn't since all of these commits were merged.

Now I have a problem, where any new PR I am creating is showing all the commits that have already been merged in a prior PR unrelated to the new commits I am making to implement a new feature.

[image]

If you look into my fork it says that it's 10 commits ahead of main, even though it's actually only 4 commits ahead

---

> main: https://github.com/denoland/fresh 
> my fork: https://github.com/michael-pfister/fresh 
> old pr with merged commits: https://github.com/denoland/fresh/pull/609 
> new pr containing past commits: https://github.com/denoland/fresh/pull/614

Comment: Seems duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306012/github-pull-request-showing-commits-that-are-already-in-target-branch

Comment: @MichelKok that solution didn't work for me, must be a different issue

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to reset my fork and redo the new commits, really bad user experience.

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22440

Comment: Yes, it's annoying. But it's generally bad practice to push PR/MR content from a Fork to main. I'd recommend you for your next PR to push your changes to a new Branch, that Branch can be deleted after the PR is merged and you can update your main with your squashed changes.