# Git merge no history commit

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-merge, git-pull

i want to have no other branch history commit when i merge other branch to master. how can i do it ?

as we know:

git pull **--rebase** origin test #  mean: only history commit no merge commit.

git pull **--no-ff**  origin test #  mean: history commit and merge commit.

git pull **--ff-only** origin test # mean: only history commit no merge commit.

i want to "**only merge commit** ", how ? pls. like this:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master
[image]

**further question:**

if i use "**--squash**", it will not auto log  "Merge branch 'xxx' of xxxx" or "Merge tag 'xxx' of xxxx" when merge. need write it on my hand ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can also configure the branch where you merge to automatically squash the commits you want to merge in (as in [this discussion](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Is-there-a-way-to-add-a-default-squash-flag-for-all-merges-into-a-head-td6098715.html)):

```
git config branch.<name>.mergeoptions --squash
```

[`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) has:

```
branch.<name>.mergeoptions
```

> Sets default options for merging into branch `<name>`.
>   The syntax and supported options are the same as those of [git-merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), but option values containing whitespace characters are currently not supported.

That way, you don't have to add any extra option to your `git merge`.

As mentioned in "[In git, what is the difference between `merge --squash` and `rebase`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/6309)", that won't record a merge though:

This would record a merge:

```
git config branch.<name>.mergeoptions --no-ff
```

Comment: see "further question", can u give me some advice ?

Comment: @kangear in your case, a no-ff would be more adapted: I have adied the answer.

Answer (score 1):

i get answer:

```
   --squash, --no-squash
       Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened
       (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit or
       move the HEAD, nor record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD to cause the next git commit
       command to create a merge commit. This allows you to create a single commit
       on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another
       branch (or more in case of an octopus).
```

git pull **--squash** origin test

**It's ok!**