# Why is the Git feature branch still visible after merge and deletion?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

#### Steps taken

I merged a `feature` branch back into `master` and deleted the `feature` branch. But it still shows up in the tree.

#### Result

Tree visualisation in SourceTree *before* deleting the feature branch:
[image: Tree before deleting the feature branch]

Tree visualisation in SourceTree *after* deleting the feature branch:
[image: Tree after deleting the feature branch]

The `feature` branch in the left-hand list is gone, as expected, and the label in the tree visualisation is gone as well, again as expected.

#### Questions

But:

1. Why is the violet part still shown?
2. Which Git commands would I have needed to execute to not see the violet part anymore? I probably answered this question myself two sections further down.

I understand that the final commit in the screenshot above has two parents.
But I don't understand why the violet commit which happened on the feature branch is not inside the final merged commit on `master` (which would, I think, mean that the violet branch shouldn't be visible anymore after deleting it).

#### Replay of steps from the command line (instead of SourceTree)

I replayed it on the command line (just to check whether SourceTree did what I thought it did) and the final step was a `git merge feature`. Same situation:

[image: Tree visualisation on the command line]

#### Trial with `--squash`

I undid the last merge and tried this:

```
git merge --squash feature
git commit "Squashed merge"
git delete -D feature # Note that -d did not work; it said "error: The branch 'feature' is not fully merged."
```

And now it shows what I would have expected in the first place. One straight line and no indication of the `feature` branch ever existing:

[image: Straight tree line after --squash]

#### Question

3. How is this merge different from the previous merge?

I guess I sort of pieced together what happens with those merges after all the trial and error above, but I would be grateful if someone could really explain in detail what the semantic difference of the above steps are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You still see the violet part because you dit a `git merge`, which creates a merge commit assembling the two branches. Since branches have diverged, this is a "non fast forward" merge, this is why the history will still show this kind of tree.
2. You don't want the violet part ? Use `git rebase` instead of `git merge`. In your case:

   - `git checkout master`
   - `git rebase feature`
   - `git branch -d feature`

This will replay the commits of `feature` on `master` before the divergence. You'll have a straight line in your history log.

3. You did a `git merge --squash` which quite alike a rebase - but you're squashing all the commits of the source branch in one commit (in your case you only have one commit, so it doesn't really show)

Comment: Your second point was very helpful and it explains how to avoid getting the violet part in the first place. However, let's say I did perform a `git merge feature` and then another dozen commits on top of it on `master`: how can I make the violet part disappear so late in the game? Let's further assume I haven't pushed anything so rewriting history was acceptable. How would one do that?

Comment: Assuming you didn't push anything, it's still doable. With a dozen commits on top, it depends ... You have two solutions : 1) Those commits are not too tied with the merge ? You can do an interactive rebase (it seems a little hard) - 2) `git reset` just before the merge, `git stash` your modifications, `git rebase feature` then `git stash pop` to retrieve your modifications, and redo your commits

Comment: @topheman Trying point 2: The "feature" was deleted, after the reset I don't see the branch "feature" again?

Comment: Not a reset, a rebase: that's why you won't need this feature branch anymore on this scenario where you want to import code from feature to master.

Comment: While the high level concepts are mostly correct, I assume your second point was supposed to be the other way around? `git checkout feature`, `git rebase master`, `git checkout master`, `git branch -d feature`?

Answer (score 4):

When you delete a branch, you're deleting a pointer to a commit, not the commit itself. If there are no other references to the commit, then the commit can eventually be garbage-collected, but the merged commit creates a reference to that commit (since that commit is its parent).

The initial `merge` workflow creates a merge commit with two parents, and the second parent commit still exists even if the branch pointing at it does not.

When you do `git merge --squash`, you are effectively causing a `rebase` of your commit onto the target branch, which gives you the linear history instead of the dual-parent history. For the distinction between that command and `rebase`, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427238/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-merge-squash-and-rebase).

Comment: Nice link. It says there for `git merge --squash` "without marking any merge relationship". That's the part I didn't understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Lernkurve. You are welcome. If you want to rewrite your history, you need to decide exactly what you want your history to look like. For example, do you want a dozen commits on top of your `master` branch or just one commit that is equivalent to all of them?

Comment: I'm interested in the first example where I can keep the dozen commits on top of `master`. But for learning purposes, I'm also interested in the example where there is one commit that is equivalent to all of them.

Comment: @Lernkurve, Create a new branch and use squash / rebase, and then cherry-pick the rest of the commits from master on top.

Comment: Worked! :-) I just cherry-picked the hell out of it with [ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch). Delightful! Thank you very much.