# Why are my changes gone after a cancelled git commit and how do I recover them?

Tags: git, husky, git-husky, lint-staged

Here's what I did:

1. Coded 8 hours worth of changes.
2. `git status` displays all my changes.
3. `git add -A`
4. `git commit -m "Foo"`. A pre-commit git hook fires with `husky` and `lint-staged`.
5. I remember that there's a TypeScript typing error I failed to fix, so I press Ctrl+C to cancel.
6. Absentmindedly, I run `git commit -m "Foo"` again and immediately cancel.
7. Changes are gone! The files are reverted, `git status` is clean, `git log` and `git reflog` do not show a new commit.

Why did my changes get reverted? How do I recover them?

[image: step 1] [image: step 2]

Comment: Do two things, first immediately check the history of each file in VS Code to see if you can recover your work from the IDE.  Second, figure out what this hook is doing.  I saw a "cleanup" task mentioned.  Could it actually wipe your working directory and stage?  Not sure, but you need to investigate this.

Comment: Use `git reflog` to see if the commit was done. As you have run `git add -A`, the contents of the changed files (whose names are in green) are stored in blobs. Don't remove `.git` and you can finally find them back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/recover-dangling-blobs-in-git/9560317 may help if the commit was not done.

Comment: I'd guess the problem here is lint-staged, not git.

Comment: `lint-staged` has a long history of [developers losing work](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues?q=is%3Aissue+lost+is%3Aclosed) - my personal recommendation would be to not use it; a pre-commit hook should do nothing more than validate and exit.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

OK, it was `lint-staged` to blame. It stashed my changes.

So running `git stash apply` recovered them!

---

⚠ Do not attempt running multiple instances of `lint-staged` in parallel on the same git repo (e. g. on each project in a monorepo). This will destroy your changes without any way to recover them.

If you work on a monorepo, either lint projects sequentially or give up `lint-staged` and lint the whole codebase, including unstaged files.

Comment: It probably uses `git stash -k`. This is a tempting approach in writing pre-commit hooks, but I think it has way too many failure modes. You've just encountered one of the worse ones.

Comment: Cool. Stash is evil and you should try to avoid it, use `git worktree instead`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133883/how-to-work-on-the-multiple-different-branches-where-i-can-switch-easily-between/38134131#38134131

Comment: @CodeWizard it is not the OP's choice how lint-staged works. Not sure why you are recommending a pre-commit hook creates a new worktree though?

Comment: Thank you so much, i thought i lost my 1 month changes , tq so much

Comment: Haha, no prob, don't forget to upvote the question and the answer.

Comment: this answer saved me from a meltdown. thank you

Comment: why lint-staged do this though. I was stunned when I see all my changes gone.

Comment: @PhucVuong, `lint-staged` needs to remove unstaged edits from the codebase, so that the linter only sees staged edits. `git stash` is a natural way of hiding edits and restoring them later..

Comment: Thanks! I faced the same situation: failed lint-staged git hook (because of the missed `npm i` on another machine) and all my work has disappeared without new commit created. I already started to think that all the work is lost, but your answer saved me.

Comment: THANK YOU LIFE SAVIOUR I WAS GOING NUTS FOR TWO HOURS! thought i have lost 10h of work.. bloody lint

Comment: Many thanks! My head almost became grey when the code disappered

Answer (score 7):

For all of you who are: TL;DR
- **Option 1** - which you mentioned you already did: use `git reflog` && `git reset`
- **Option 2** - Use your editor history
- **Option 3** - If you added those files grab them from the staging area **but** you will need to find them

```
# Find all dangling files
git fsck --all

## Now use git cat-file -p to print those hashes
git cat-p <SHA-1>
```

---

#### Full answer:

Before answering, let's add some background, explaining what this `HEAD` is.

## ***`First of all what is HEAD?`***

`HEAD` is simply a reference to the current commit (latest) on the current branch. 
There can only be a single `HEAD` at any given time (excluding `git worktree`).

The content of `HEAD` is stored inside `.git/HEAD` and it contains the 40 bytes SHA-1 of the current commit.

---

## ***`detached HEAD`***

If you are not on the latest commit - meaning that `HEAD` is pointing to a prior commit in history it's called ***`detached HEAD`***.

[image]

On the command line, it will look like this - SHA-1 instead of the branch name since the `HEAD` is not pointing to the tip of the current branch:

[image]

[image]

---

#### A few options on how to recover from a detached HEAD:

---

#### [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

```
git checkout <commit_id>
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X // x is the number of commits t go back
```

This will checkout new branch pointing to the desired commit. 
This command will checkout to a given commit. 
At this point, you can create a branch and start to work from this point on.

```
# Checkout a given commit.
# Doing so will result in a `detached HEAD` which mean that the `HEAD`
# is not pointing to the latest so you will need to checkout branch
# in order to be able to update the code.
git checkout <commit-id>

# Create a new branch forked to the given commit
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

---

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

You can always use the `reflog` as well. 
`git reflog` will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

#### ***[`git reset --hard <commit_id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)***

"Move" your HEAD back to the desired commit.

```sh
# This will destroy any local modifications.
# Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternatively, if there's work to keep:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# This saves the modifications, then reapplies that patch after resetting.
# You could get merge conflicts if you've modified things which were
# changed since the commit you reset to.
```

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt)) you can also use the `git rebase --no-autostash` as well.

---

#### ***[`git revert <sha-1>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)***

"Undo" the given commit or commit range. 
The reset command will "undo" any changes made in the given commit. 
A new commit with the undo patch will be committed while the original commit will remain in the history as well.

```sh
# Add a new commit with the undo of the original one.
# The <sha-1> can be any commit(s) or commit range
git revert <sha-1>
```

---

This schema illustrates which command does what. 
As you can see there, `reset && checkout` modify the `HEAD`.

[image]