# git add same files in precommit after formatting, cannot add deleted files

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, husky

I have a react project where we have been manually formatting our code before every push. So logically I setup the `precommit` hook using `husky`.

This is the precommit hook

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

added_files=$(git diff --name-only --cached)

yarn fix
git add ${added_files}
```

I want to "re-add" the same files, as it was intended by the author of commit (yarn fix runs over the whole project).

Now this hook works perfectly, until I have some deleted files.

output of `git status`:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   .babelrc
        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   package.json
        modified:   public/index.html
        deleted:    src/App.css
```

Output of `git diff --name-only --cached`:

```
.babelrc
.gitignore
package.json
public/index.html
src/App.css
```

Output of `pre-commit` hook:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ semistandard --fix
Done in 1.23s.
fatal: pathspec 'src/App.css' did not match any files
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 128 (error)
```

Seems like deleted files cannot be "re-added". What would be a better solution?

Comment: Note that it is generally a bad idea to `git add` files in a pre-commit hook. For instance, this doesn't work right with `git add -p` and partially-staged files. Pre-commit hooks should just *inspect* the proposed commit. If you know what you're doing, though, and remember that your particular setup prohibits using `git add -p`, you can indeed make this work (as you did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was too simple. Fixed by adding [--diff-filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203), which would filter out deleted files.

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

added_files=$(git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d)

yarn fix
git add ${added_files}
```

Comment: If your answer solved your problem, consider marking it as the accepted answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60335168  to revert back. So running _git stash_ apply recovered them!