# lint-staged custom config > error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: next.js, eslint, husky, lint-staged

I'm following the first example (copy/paste) of custom config file (lint-staged.config.js) for lint-staged packaged from its [github README](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) without success. I get `error Command failed with exit code 1.` always.

### I tried this...

I have tried three things, for each case I had my `lint-staged.config.js` in the root directory.

1. package.json: result is `error Command failed with exit code 1.`

```
"lint-staged": {
        "packages/**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
            "yarn lint-staged --config ./lint-staged.config.js"
        ]
    },
```

2. husky/pre-commit: result is `error Command failed with exit code 1.`

```
npx lint-staged --config ../lint-staged.config.js
```

3. cmd line: result is `error Command failed with exit code 1.`

```
yarn lint-staged --config lint-staged.config.js
```

### The problem

Im just looking for run a custom config file.

The problem is that the execution fails, the error message its related to the command but the command itself its correct as `lint-staged [options]` (yarn/npx lint-staged -h) then to provide a custom config file it would as `lint-staged [--config [path]]` but it fails (I even provide all kind of quotes for path).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when the module doesn't provide an explicit positive answer to the validation it will always return `error Command failed with exit code 1` meaning that the validation has fail.

To properly work as expected it should, in my case:

1. first, the module had to have a return.
2. Secondly it should be in form of string array.
3. Third, the first string of the array had to be terminal-like response as '0' or 'true' of 'false'.

Then, the next following strings could be a message or messages like 'error some A' and 'error some B' and 'error some C' and so on...

For example: `['0', 'error some A', 'error some B', 'error some C']`

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = (absolutePaths) => {
  const cwd = process.cwd();
  const relativePaths = absolutePaths.map((file) => path.relative(cwd, file));
  console.log("query", relativePaths)
  return ['0', 'error some A', 'error some B', 'error some C']
};
```

This runs ok, but as Andrey Mikhaylov said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60335168/9270078) to run something like

```
"lint-staged": {
        "packages/**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
            "yarn lint-staged --config ./lint-staged.config.js"
        ]
    },
```

If the lint returns **an error, It will blow away the staged files** causing a regression that will drop the commit completely, which means that all the work will be lost.

I fix this not intended/desired behaviour running the same command `yarn lint-staged --config ./lint-staged.config.js` but from husky at the pre-commit file as

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn lint-staged --config ./lint-staged.config.js`
```