# Git: Push differences between two branches of different repos as a single commit to another repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-squash

I made a fork of my public Github repo on a private Gitlab repo.
I made several commits in a single branch of the fork and want to push all these changes (differences between public repo branch and private repo branch) as a single commit to the public repo branch on GitHub again.
I only want to use the command line.

Does anybody know how to do this?
I think it's something with git squash.

Comment: Take a look at this: [How to git pretty](http://justinhileman.info/article/changing-history/). The section you might be interested in is called *Reset and re-commit*, but you have multiple options. Or actually the section right after that, using an interactive commit (and squashing).

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your response! I will try that.

Comment: @Henrix have you solve the problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

See my old answer "[In git, what is the difference between `merge --squash` and `rebase`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/6309) "

You can make another branch in your private repo, `merge --squash` your fix branch on it, and push that new branch composed of a single commit.

```
git checkout -b newBranch origin/master
git merge --squash my_fix_branch
git push -u origin newBranch
```

From your remote private repo on GitHub, you can make a pull request from that new pushed branch, to merge that single commit back into the original repo.