# How to rewrite the master branch history to other Repository master branch

Tags: git, git-commit, git-history-graph

Is there any way or any tool or commands to re write the history of `master`  or some `A` branch ***from some commit number*** to newly created `master` branch of **NEW REPOSITORY** with `master` branch with 0 commits or no history.

In such a way that :

1. All the previous commits before commit number "45678" should be re written as single commit in the new repository master branch
2. Rewriting the history should begin from commit "45678"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I don't have a suitable sacrificial repository to test this: you've been warned).

I would think `merge --squash` could do this.

- Add new repository as remote
- Create dest branch, push branch with upstream tracking to the new repository
- Checkout the new branch
- `Merge --squash` from your source branch
- Commit
- Push to the new repository

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/67392) as well.)

**Old Content (before question edit)**

Just create the new repository as a new remote on your clone of the original repository; and then push to the new repository.

```
git remote add newrep url-to-new-repository
git push -u newrep master
```

Repeat the last command for each branch you want to push.

Comment: Will it push the history from the start of source repo ? I dont want to rewrite all the history but from some commit number , but it should get all the files older from that commit , is it possible ?

Comment: @ShanKhan I wondered if you wanted that. Please clarify in the question.

Comment: i get error as failed to push some ref to that repo.

Comment: @ShanKhan "I get an error" isn't a helpful comment.