# Merge commit without squash vs with squash option

Tags: git, merge, version-control, smartgit

On daily routine i use `SmartGit` as client of choose. My team members however stick to git native, non commercial GUI. We discovered some differences in how our merge commits looks like.

Those are options that `SmartGit` gives when requested to merge branch:
[image: SmartGit commits type]

On below graph you can see my example SmartGit graph output, containing:

- single `master` branch
- One branch merged to master with `merge commit` option
- One branch merged with `simple commit` option

One of branches (`with_merge_branch`) is visualizing merge operation by joining branch with master via line. Second one (`normal_commit_branch`) does not.

[image: git tree]

Question is, how to enforce both behaviors in native git commands? I.e. whats the difference between those two commits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In git, what is the difference between merge --squash and rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427238/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-merge-squash-and-rebase)

Comment: I've never used it, but git merge with the squash option removes any trace of there being a second parent branch.  If you follow the duplicate link, you'll see some examples of why you might want to use it.  Merging without the squash option is the default behavior of `git merge`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The difference between the two kinds of merge are only **different in the commit history** (as you showed the logs in graph).

Let's illustrate by graphs. Assume the commit history as below before merging:

```
A---B---C---D  master
     \
      E---F---G  develop
```

#### Merge commit (multiple parents):

The command used is `git merge branchname`. It's the default way to merge two branches.

When you merge `develop` branch into `master` branch by **Merge commit** in SmartGit  (`git merge develop`), the commit history will be:

```
A---B---C---D---M  master
     \         /
      E---F---G    develop
```

#### Simple commit (one parent, "squash"):

It merges two branches with `--squash` option, the command used is `git merge branchname --squash`.

> [--squash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make
>   a commit, move the HEAD, or record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD (to cause the
>   next git commit command to create a merge commit). This allows you to
>   create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is
>   the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

When you merge `develop` branch into `master` branch by **simple commit** in SmartGit (`git merge develop --squash`), it get the changes from `develop` branch into `master` branch as a new ordinary commit (as if a real merge happened), and the commit history will be:

```
A---B---C---D---M  master
     \                 
      E---F---G    develop
```

Comment: Just to supplement fantastic answer by @Marina, in case of some integrations (in my case it's GitLab) internal merge request system is unable to detect merged branches if once use `-squash` commit into parent branch. So on one side you have cleaner history but detection of merge origin is a bit harder

Comment: I think, a warning is in order: **Squash commits lose history!** If you merge, `git` will know all the intermediate step that lead to the feature integration, and `git bisect` will be able to pinpoint any regression to one of these intermediate steps. If you squash, your feature branch becomes a black box to git, and `git bisect` will only be able to point out the one squash commit that contains the entire feature development. Best embrace the DAG history model of `git` wholeheartedly, it'll save you many headaches down the road.

Answer (score 1):

`merge commits` are just `commit` but the difference is they have more than one parents. 
as you know commits may or may not have parent commit, in fact the `merge commit` is the `commit` that have more than one `parent commit`.