# why does my repo is showing behind the upstream after squash commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

I have forked a repo and I commit and push new changes and merged changes came from pull upstream after doing squash. So isn't is supposed to show

```
The branch is x commits ahead of upstream:master"
```

Instead its showing

```
The branch is x commits ahead of upstream:master and y behind of upstream:master
```

Isn't it strange?
because I have merged upstream code and committed it along with my new code.

Comment: You are behind because you don't have the squash.

Answer (score 0):

Being ahead and behind means a divergent history.

But if you did a `merge --squash` (result from a pull, which is a fetch + merge), it only added a new commit, it did *not* rewrite the history.
See "[In git, what is the difference between merge --squash and rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/6309)".

If you did squashing of your local history (previously pushed), *then* the history is rewritten, and you would get an "ahead/behind" message