# Merge git --squash branch into master does not appear in gitlab website?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I merged my development branch called `SGMII` with the `--squash` option into the master branch as followed:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge --squash SGMII
git commit -m "merge SGMII into master"
git push
```

However, when checked it on the gitlab website, it does not display the merge:

[image: gitlab-graph]

In addition, the `SGMII` branch is not marked as *merged*. Do you have any idea why they are not consistent?

Comment: That's how `git merge --squash` works. It creates a new non-merge commit in the target branch which introduces the changes from the other branch. If you want to see the merge commit in the graph, you need `git merge --no-ff`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good to know. However, also a compare on the gitlab page between `master` and `SGMII` did not show the required changes. There was nothing pushed into the master in the meanwhile. Therefore, the SGMII branch and the master should be equal (and in fact, they are). But the compare marks it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a [`git merge --squash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---squash) illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427238/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-merge-squash-and-rebase/2427520#2427520): it does not produce a merge commit.

> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but:
>
> - do not actually make a commit,
> - do no move the `HEAD`, or
> - do not record `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` (to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit).
>
> Therefore, the `SGMII` branch and the `master` should be equal (and in fact, they are). But the compare marks it differently.

If `master` is properly configured, the `git push` command should have pushed the local `master` to its remote GitLab repository `origin/master` upstream branch.