# I have created a PR in stash,the pr has multiple commits and to squash them there was conflict issue

Tags: git

There are 2 repo upstream(main repo) and origin(my repo). PR has merge conflict and to resolve it executed below commands

Step 1. On master branch

Step 2. git pull origin master

Step 3.git checkout my_branch

Step 4. git rebase master

Step 5.git status

Your branch and 'my_branch' have diverged,
and have 118 and 106 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

please help as the branch is displaying a lot of commits from different developers. If the process is incorrect please guide.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with java, javascript or selenium. Remove those tags.

Comment: Have you tried `git rebase origin/master -i`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried "git pull --rebase"  in  my_branch and after this command, it displays around 400 commits in my_branch. It gives below message Your branch and 'my_branch' have diverged,
and have 118 and 106 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Answer (score 1):

Once you have rebase your PR branch on top of the updated master, all you have to do is push it back.

Since the rebase has rewritten the history of that PR branch, you can simply, ofr the PR branch, force push it

```
git checkout my_pr_branch
git push --force
```

That will update the PR.
Since the PR branch has been rebased on top of `master`, it will be trivial to be integrated by the maintainer of the original repo to the `master` branch (fast-forward merge)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Does this squash the multiple commits into one commit after pushing .

Comment: @Amitaj Only if you have squashed them locally (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/6309). But even if you didn't, the maintainer can still squash them on merge: https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits

Comment: Can we execute the command "git pull --rebase" on the pr branch as when I did this it pulled all the 400 commits in my PR branch and when pushed everything got pushed to the PR  because of which I have the decline the PR.hence can we say that git pull --rebase should not be executed on pr branch anytime

Comment: @Amitaj Yes, you should rebase your PR branch on top of upstream/master.